# overloading in inheritance c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

so I got this problem while trying to overload in c++:
I have those classes:

```
class Data
{
public:
    void virtual f(){cout<<"In data!"<<endl;}
};

class A: public Data
{
public:
    void f(int x){cout<<"Class A int is: "<<x<<endl;}

};
```

then I do:

```
Data *D=new A();
D->f(4);
```

I expect the Data's f() function to do to class A's f() function since I did it virtual, but it won't.

Any ways to make it work?

Answer (score 7):

That's not the same function, the one in the derived class takes an `int` parameter.

That shouldn't even compile, because `Data` doesn't have a method called `f(int)`.

For polymorphism to work, you need the same signature:

```
class Data
{
public:
    void virtual f(int){cout<<"In data!"<<endl;}
    //              |
    //        dummy parameter
};

class A: public Data
{
public:
    void f(int x){cout<<"Class A int is: "<<x<<endl;}
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to add new overloading function to the child class?

Comment: @nhahtdh it is possible. But overloading is different from overriding. And in his snippet, it's neither. It's hiding. :)

Comment: I want the Data one to get "Data" and the A one to get "A". is it possible?

Comment: @Jjang have you modified the signature in the base class as I said?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same parameters when overloading. Your compiler sees doStuff(int a), doStuff(String a) and doStuff() as different functions. Be sure they all have the same parameters when you're overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading does not work across class boundaries.
Here is something you can do to be able to call both using an object of class A -

```
class Data
{
public:
    void virtual f(){cout<<"In data!"<<endl;}
    //              |
    //        dummy parameter
};

class A: public Data
{
    using Data::f;

public:
    void f(int x){cout<<"Class A int is: "<<x<<endl;}
};
```